# Django list rendered as string in template - cannot access list value

Tags: django, list

*The problem :* I try to iterate over a list which is the result of the selection of multiple items in a form (use of forms.MultipleChoiceField). This is then saved in my db using models.Charfield and passed from the view to the template through context_dict `(context_dict['attachment'] = attachment.pieces_jointes)`
However I think that it is not saved as a list but as a string. Instead of:

```
[u'essai document', u'essai document 2', u'essai document5'],
```

I think I have (because of model field type):

```
"[u'essai document', u'essai document 2', u'essai document5']"
```

Indeed, in my template if I type :

```
{% for attachment in attachments %}
    {{attachment.pieces_jointes.1}}
 {% endfor %}
```

I get for that record:

```
u
```

and not :

```
essai document 2
```

For your information, if I open the admin and look at the value recorded I have :

```
[u'essai document', u'essai document 2', u'essai document5']
```

I have tried to get rid of the possible "" which could be around the list but I haven't succeeded. Can anyone explain my how I can turn that string back into a list and iterate over it in my template?
Thanks

A bit of code as requested:

models.py

```
class Document (models.Model):
    dpseudo = models.ForeignKey(Identite)
    dnom = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    dphoto = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_document', blank=False)
    ddate_ajout = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
                self.slug = slugify(self.dpseudo) + slugify(self.dnom) + slugify(self.ddate_ajout)
        super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):  #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
        return self.dnom



class Attachment (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    date_creation = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    statut = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    pieces_jointes = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Attachment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):  #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
import ast

def attacher(request):
    piece_list = Attachment.objects.all()
    attachment_list =[ast.literal_eval(i) for i in Attachment.objects.values_list('pieces_jointes', flat=True)]

    context_dict = {'pieces': piece_list, 'nom_pieces_jointes' : attachment_list}

    return render(request, 'job/attacher.html', context_dict)
```

forms.py

```
class AttachmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name.")
    pieces_jointes = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttchmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pieces_jointes'].choices = [(document.dnom, document.dnom) for document in Document.objects.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = Attchment
        fields = ('name','pieces_jointes')
```

As advised, I used ast.literal_eval() in my views but I get an error :

unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have saved `attachment.pieces_jointes` as string :

```
"[u'essai document', u'essai document 2', u'essai document5']"
```

you can use `ast.literal_eval` in your `view` to pass the list in template:

```
>>> import ast
>>> l=ast.literal_eval("[u'essai document', u'essai document 2', u'essai document5']")
>>> l[1]
u'essai document 2'
```